# MySQL doesn't seem to work correct

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this college database where i have to Retrieve names of instructors teaching Computer Science courses, the sections (course number, section number, year, semester) they are teaching, and the total number of students in the sections

So far this is what have managed but the output is not correct.

```
SELECT  i.instructor_id,o.year,o.semester,o.section_number, o.number as CourseNumber,o.Total_num_student
FROM Instructor i JOIN
(SELECT t.instructor_id,t.year,t.semester,t.section_number,o1.number,o1.Total_num_student
 FROM teaches t JOIN
 (SELECT COUNT(s.student_id) as Total_num_student,e.section_number,e.number 
  FROM Student s JOIN
  enrolls e
  ON s.student_id=e.student_id
  GROUP BY section_number,e.number) as o1
 ON o1.section_number=t.section_number) as o
on i.instructor_id=o.instructor_id
WHERE department='Computer Science';
```

Can you see what is wrong with the output.

```
create table Course (
  number int,
  title varchar(255),
  credits int,
  syllabus varchar(255),
PRIMARY KEY (number)
  );
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (620,'Algorithm',3,'XYZ');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (621,'Algorithm',3,'XYZ');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (232,'Java',2,'ABC');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (420,'Cpp',2,'PQRS');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (720,'Big Data',3,'NVGY');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (120,'Intelligent System',4,'KJHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (220,'Operating System',3,'GED');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (480,'Graphics',4,'RSFN');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (520,'Distributed Networks',3,'NHU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (820,'Data Mining',3,'TYU');
INSERT INTO Course VALUES (700,'Cryptography',1,'MNO');

create table Student (
  student_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id)
  );

INSERT INTO Student VALUES (2345,'Mike','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (346,'Rob','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (789,'Nick','Game Design');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (675,'Sara','Computer Science');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (123,'Raj','Chemical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (5331,'Jack','Biotech');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (1023,'Michelle','Chemical');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (9800,'Jie','Game Design');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (7834,'Dan','Petroleum');
INSERT INTO Student VALUES (4567,'Patrick','Computer Science');


create table Instructor (
  instructor_id int,
  name varchar(255),
  department varchar(255),
  title varchar(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id)
  );


INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (12,'John','Computer Science','Java');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (23,'Bischof','Mechanical','Drawing');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (56,'Kwon','Biotech','Biology');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (78,'Deever','Security','Cryptography');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (45,'Jin','Computer Science','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (67,'Bailey','Petroleum','Metalurgy');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (90,'Richard','Industrial','Manufacture');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (11,'Joe','Chemical','Chemistry');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (24,'Roger','Game Design','Cpp');
INSERT INTO Instructor VALUES (55,'Zack','Computer Science','Design');


create table CourseOffering (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  classroom int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (620,2012,2,102,3540);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (621,2013,3,103,3545);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2650);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (720,2013,3,100,3455);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (120,2014,1,102,3000);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (220,2008,2,104,1450);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (480,2009,4,106,1400);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (520,2010,3,102,3500);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2700);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering VALUES (700,2012,1,103,2540);

create table CourseOffering_Timing (
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  timing int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,year,semester,section_number,timing),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course (number)
  );

INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (620,2012,2,102,9);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (621,2013,3,103,9);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (232,2011,1,103,3);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (420,2013,3,101,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (720,2013,3,100,5);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (120,2014,1,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (220,2008,2,104,10);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (480,2009,4,106,12);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (520,2010,3,102,4);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (820,2008,3,100,2);
INSERT INTO CourseOffering_Timing VALUES (700,2012,1,103,3);

create table PreRequisite (
  number int,
  prerequisite_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (number,prerequisite_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number) REFERENCES Course(number)
  );

INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (620,480);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (621,481);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (232,120);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (420,320);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (720,580);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (120,110);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (220,130);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (480,380);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (520,360);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (820,700);
INSERT INTO PreRequisite VALUES (700,610);


create table enrolls (
  student_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  grade varchar(10),
  PRIMARY KEY (student_id,number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (number,year,semester,section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering(number,year,semester,section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (student_id) REFERENCES Student (student_id)  
  );

INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (2345,620,2012,2,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (346,232,2011,1,103,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (789,420,2013,3,101,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (675,621,2013,3,103,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (123,120,2014,1,102,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (5331,220,2008,2,104,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (1023,480,2009,4,106,'B');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (9800,520,2010,3,102,'A');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (7834,820,2008,3,100,'C');
INSERT INTO enrolls VALUES (4567,700,2012,1,103,'F');

create table teaches (
  instructor_id int,
  number int,
  year int,
  semester int,
  section_number int,
  PRIMARY KEY (instructor_id, number, year, semester, section_number),
  FOREIGN KEY (instructor_id) REFERENCES Instructor(instructor_id),
  FOREIGN KEY ( number, year, semester, section_number) REFERENCES CourseOffering( number, year, semester, section_number)
  );



INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (12,620,2012,2,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (12,621,2013,3,103);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (23,232,2011,1,103);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (56,420,2013,3,101);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (78,720,2013,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (45,120,2014,1,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (67,220,2008,2,104);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (90,480,2009,4,106);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (11,520,2010,3,102);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (24,820,2008,3,100);
INSERT INTO teaches VALUES (55,700,2012,1,103);
```

Comment: could you give you desired result in a table format?

Comment: Providing Desired output in a tabular format will make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

See if this will work for you

```
SELECT Instructor.name AS instructor_name, teaches.section_number AS section_number,
 teaches.year AS year, teaches.semester AS semester, COUNT(enrolls.student_id) FROM Instructor
 INNER JOIN teaches ON teaches.instructor_id = Instructor.instructor_id 
 INNER JOIN enrolls ON teaches.section_number = enrolls.section_number AND teaches.semester = enrolls.semester AND teaches.year = enrolls.year
 WHERE department='Computer Science' 
 GROUP BY Instructor.name, teaches.section_number, teaches.year, teaches.semester;
```

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd51de/21

The count of total students is 3. Shouldn't it be 1 as per the database ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what you are trying to achieve but this is if you like to retain the section info:

```
SELECT a.instructor_id, group_concat(DISTINCT a.year SEPARATOR ', ') YEAR, group_concat(DISTINCT a.semester SEPARATOR ', ') SEMESTER, group_concat(DISTINCT a.section_number SEPARATOR ', ') SECTION_NUMBER, group_concat(DISTINCT a.coursenumber SEPARATOR ', ') COURSENUMBER, count(a.student_id) as Total_num_student FROM (
SELECT e.student_id, i.instructor_id, t.year,t.semester,t.section_number, t.number as CourseNumber  
FROM instructor i
JOIN teaches t
ON i.instructor_id = t.instructor_id
JOIN enrolls e
ON e.section_number=t.section_number
WHERE department='Computer Science') a
GROUP BY a.instructor_id
;


SELECT a.instructor_id,  a.year, a.semester, a.section_number, a.coursenumber, count(a.student_id) as Total_num_student FROM (
SELECT e.student_id, i.instructor_id, t.year,t.semester,t.section_number, t.number as CourseNumber  
FROM instructor i
JOIN teaches t
ON i.instructor_id = t.instructor_id
JOIN enrolls e
ON e.section_number=t.section_number
WHERE department='Computer Science') a
GROUP BY a.instructor_id, a.section_number
;
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb36b/84)